# Processing - exporting a movie or image sequence from kinect data

Tags: video, image-processing, kinect, openni

I'm trying to find the fastest way to export a PNG sequence or movie with processing. I'm capturing Kinect data and currently, in each draw call, I'm using:

```
saveFrame("output/fames####.png");
```

but this is too slow. Anything I can do that's faster?

I'm using simple-openni for the kinect feed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to save to the [.oni format](http://openni.org/docs2/ProgrammerGuide.html#RecordingandPlayingData) and there's already a [SimpleOpenNI Sample](http://code.google.com/p/simple-openni/source/browse/trunk/SimpleOpenNI/dist/all/SimpleOpenNI/examples/OpenNI/RecorderPlay/RecorderPlay.pde) for recording and playing back. Even though this should use a lot of memory, I imagine it might still be faster than saveFrame()

The advantage of using the .oni format is you can easily process the nodes recorded with SimpleOpeni (for example skeleton/hand tracking or other features can be tested on a .oni recording). If you need images, there should ways to [extract/parse .oni](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/openni-dev/KAXLEmCm-xI) files

Comment: This ended up being the best solution for me in the end.

Answer (score 1):

How long does it take you to process/encode one frame (and what time is acceptable to you)? You could try to buffer the data and have it asynchronously processed by a fixed number of worker threads. Otherwise you will have to resort to capturing video because then, the installed codec can use hardware acceleration/optimized CPU based encoding.

**Edit:** To absorb the encoding latency, you can use a [Circular Buffer](http://circularbuffer.codeplex.com/) where you dump frames that need to be encoded. Then, launch [Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321424.aspx)s that encode a set of frames in parallel. Once those finish, see if there are frames in the buffer and process those.

Comment: it's just a slight (several ms delay)

Comment: Ah, then simply (circular) buffering and having multiple threads encode the image should work wonders for you.

Comment: Do you have any links / additional info on circular buffering / multiple threads?

Answer (score 0):

This might be to late, but you get a lot better performance if you save them as tif instead of png.